# Plotting a big raster file results in a white frame

Tags: r, matrix, plot, ascii, raster

I am currently working with an ASCII matrix of 256x256 pixels. I correctly imported it into R, rasterized it and the values are what I would expect (i.e., correct x and y boundaries and min and max "z" values). However, while plotting it I get a blank raster, like every value in the matrix is zero.

I tried by creating another file as a 5x5 matrix and I get no problem with that. Am I missing something?

Files and screenshots below:
[my 256x256 raster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPo33.png)

https://gofile.io/d/JGApXI ascii matrix link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your raster is simply almost empty, in the sense that it has just the 2% of values `!=0`. However if you export the raster and visualize it in a GIS software (like Qgis, or ArcMap), by setting a 100% transparency for the 0 values you can see the remaining values:

Here an example:

```
library(raster)
x <- read.table("D:/muon sideways0000.txt")
x <- as.matrix(x)
r <- raster(x)
writeRaster(r,"D:/r.tif")
z <- apply(x, 1, function(x)sum(x!=0))
sum(z)/ncell(r)*100
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To aid visualization, you can do

```
library(terra)
x <- read.table("muon sideways0000.txt")
x <- as.matrix(x)
r <- rast(x)

plot(r > 1)
```

Or some other transformation like

```
rr <- clamp(r, 0, 100)
plot(rr)
```

[image]